# How to soften edges of an image programmatically with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, qr-code

I'm looking for any solution to get QR Code with soft edge programmatically.

Any solution could be right. Post processing after QR Code generation or built in feature of any library.

Comment: What exactly is "soft edge"? There seem to be some tech companies with that name, but not programming languages or frameworks.

Comment: @phihag: Google has more than one result: http://blog.qrstyler.com/styling-qr-by-hand-soft-edges/

Comment: Yes, but no result on how to do it programmatically

Comment: @gsempe: patience. That was not meant as an answer to your question but to clarify what "soft egde" could mean. You're looking for an algorithm to soften edges in a b/w image or more precisely for a library that has that filter already implemented. A filter is a common thing in the domain of digital imaging of bitmap images.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments
@hakre I really know nothing about image processing. Any algorithm to soften edges of a b/w image should do the job

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In PHP you can use GD library to perform some filtering on qrcode image, like smoothing and median (easy to implement)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php

This is what you need.. assuming `$img` is image of qrcode.

```
$i=10;
while($i--) 
imagefilter($img,IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
imagefilter($img,IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST,-100);
```

After that use

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img,null,100);
```

to send image to output.

[image: Smooth qr code]

There is one more thing - number of iteration of gaussian blur should depend on qr code point size. Maybe you can check in loop the darkest value, if it's not 0 then stop blurring.

Comment: I'll try different parameters to do what I want. Do you have already done a such transformation with GD ?

Comment: I have done a lot transformation and filterings, with GD, other libraries and with my own algorithms. Show me what you need exactly, I'll guide you how to do that.

Comment: What I exactly need is to soften angles (get rounded corners) of a QR Code drawing like this one https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=Hello+world&choe=UTF-8&chs=400x400
All geometrical figures soften in resume.

Answer (score 0):

For the real quick-and-dirty way: Up-scale the picture x4, then down-scale it again to a quarter with [`imagecopyresampled`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php). But that's not always ideal, and yeah, [szamil answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975873/qr-code-with-soft-edge/6975931#6975931) is much better than this.